# react router not matching to route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render react component based on query string. Query string changing in browser address bar like quiz/1, quiz/2 but related component is not being render instead it is reloading page each time.

My index.js is as like below:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App';
import QuizInfo from './QuizInfo';
import QuizQuestions from './QuizQuestions';
import './index.css';

const NotFound = () => (
  <h1>404.. This page is not found!</h1>)

ReactDOM.render(
    (<Router history={hashHistory}>
        <App>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
              <Route path="/quiz" component={QuizInfo} >
              </Route>
              <Route path="/quiz/:id" component={QuizQuestions}>
              </Route>
              <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
            </Route>
        </App>
  </Router>),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My app.js is like below where I am rendering  element in map function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import BaseData from './baseData';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quiz_list: [],
      quiz_questions: [],
    };
    this.baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/quiz/";
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    var url = this.baseUrl+"quiz-list";
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        const quiz_list = res.data.quizList;
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ quiz_list });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to Quiz App</h2>
        </div>
        <h4> Choose any quiz to attemp</h4>
        <div className="quiz-list">
            {this.state.quiz_list.map((quiz, index) =>
              <li key={index}>
                <Link to={`/quiz/${quiz.id}`}>{quiz.name}</Link>
              </li>
            )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't wrap routes around each other in React Router 4. Look at the below example to see how you can get around some of the problems that may happen when you migrate from React Router 3 to 4. Including a fix for your no path matches Route.

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, hashHistory, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => <div>Hi</div>
const QuizInfo = () => <div>Quiz Info</div>
const QuizQuestions = props => <div>{props.match.params.id}</div>
const NotFound = () => <h1>404.. This page is not found!</h1>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/quiz">Quiz</Link>
      <Link to="/quiz/12">Quiz 12</Link>
      <Link to="/gloop">NA</Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route exact path="/quiz" component={QuizInfo}/>
        <Route path="/quiz/:id" component={QuizQuestions}/>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks @win.. Wrapping route  list into <Switch> solved my problem. But I am unable to understand why?. It is necessary to wrap routes in Switch?

Comment: @Noone Switch will basically switch the `Route` based on which path was matched. We can no longer wrap routes like what you did in the above example in RR4. It is also important that `/quiz` has exact on its route because `/quiz/12` will trigger `/quiz` route first (because of the order and the switch)